# PHP Mysql - retorno de duplicados

Tags: php, mysql

Bom pessoal a minha dúvida é o seguinte: Como eu posso estar fazendo a verificação para saber se já existe tal valor no banco de dados?

Eu tenho esse código aqui que já é feito a verificação pela Query SQL mesmo, ou seja se não existir tal valor ele inseri e se existir ele não inseri, Isso está funcionando perfeitamente.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO usuarios(nome,apelido) 
    SELECT "'.$valor[0].'", "'.$valor[1].'"
    FROM DUAL
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT nome,apelido FROM usuarios 
       WHERE nome = "'.$valor[0].'" OR apelido = "'.$valor[1].'")';

$resultado = $MySQLi->query($sql) OR trigger_error($MySQLi->error, E_USER_ERROR);

if($resultado == 1) { 
  echo 'sucesso'; 
} else { 
    echo 'já existe esse nome ou nick'; 
}
```

O problema está em receber essa notificação e dizer ao usuario se já existe, porque ele sempre retorna 1 na variável $resultado sendo assim não posso dizer ao usuario se foi inserido ou se já existe o valor.

Alguém poderia me dizer uma forma funcional para fazer essa verificação?

Comment: Não sei qual API você usar para fazer as consultas mas a ideia é pegar o número de linhas retornadas pela consulta, `$resultado` me parece um resource, ai sua comaparação é `se(resource == 1)`, quando deveria ser algo como `se($total_registros  >= 1)`

Comment: Beleza, Eu vou postar aqui a Classe que estou usando para fazer a consulta.

Comment: http://blog.thiagobelem.net/php-e-mysql-para-iniciantes-consulta-simples

Comment: Sabe dizer se é MySQL ou MySQLi? não tenho acesso ao link ... tente pegar o número de linhas com [mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php), deve ficar algo assim, `$resultado = $MySQLi->query(....); echo $resultado->num_rows;` deve aparecer algum número, aí é so fazer a comparação certa ;)

Comment: `if($mysqli->affected_rows >= 1){ echo 'sucesso';} else {echo 'já existe'; };`

Comment: Beleza, vou testar e dou o retorno.

Comment: Diego Felipe, Muito Obrigado o techo Código que você mandou funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problema:**

Isso deve ocorrer porque a função:

```
if($resultado == 1){
```

Seria equivalente a isso:

```
if($MySQLi->query($sql) == 1){
```

Isso sempre irá retornar `true`/`1` caso o `query` seja executado com sucesso, acredito eu. Isso não leva em consideração se não houver nenhuma inserção/atualização de conteúdo. O único erro que pode resultar é se houver erro na própria construção do query. O mais comum, além de sintaxe, seria tentar inserir um conteúdo nulo onde não é permitido, por exemplo.

**Solução:**

Neste caso de INSERT/UPDATE/REPLACE/DELETE:

```
if($MySQLi->affected_rows >= 1){
  echo 'sucesso'; 
}else{ 
    echo 'já existe esse nome ou nick'; 
}
```

O `$resultado->affected_rows` irá "contar" quantas linhas foram alteradas/inseridas, isso irá identificar de fato se houve a inserção/atualização da query que deseja.

No caso de SELECT:

```
if($resultado->num_rows === 0){
// No caso de select geralmente é invertido, quando não existe resultado (==0) é porque o usuário está disponível, como em APIs de verificação antes do envio do formulário.
  echo 'sucesso'; 
}else{ 
    echo 'já existe esse nome ou nick'; 
}
```

O `$resultado->num_rows` irá "contar" quantos retornos houveram, isso irá identificar o que deseja, uma vez que se houver algum retorno é porque já existe.

> **Notas:**
>
> Acredito que seria ideal usar o `bind_param` e o `prepare` ao invés de usar diretamente o `query`, por propósitos de segurança.
>
> Uma diferença entre os dois é que o `num_rows` é feito na variável do próprio resultado (`$resultado`), enquanto o `affected_rows` é feito diretamente de onde parte a conexão com o banco de dados, no caso `$MySQLi`.